Regarding pd.get_dummies method
I have used pd.get_dummies method to encode two categorical column. As a result of which i got dummy variable columns that should contain 0 and 1 but in my case they are showing True and False values. Please explain why this is happening? Is there anything wrong here?

Have you looked at the documentation? This is the default behaviour, if you want 0/1 values you need to set the output data type using the dtype argument to either int or float.
